# Postgresql equivalent syntax for FORALL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Please share the equivalent syntax  for the below statement in postgresql

```
FORALL i IN 1..20
   INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES (enums(i));
```

Comment: FOR i IN 1..20  LOOP INSERT INTO emp2 VALUES enums(i); END LOOP  . This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO emp2
 SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,20);
```